# How to pull values from another sheet for dynamic Data validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

This one is far out of my league.
To simplify things:

**Sheet1**
`B4` has a Data validation drop down list Ex. Vancouver, Surrey, Burnaby, etc
`B5` has a Data validation drop down list Ex. 500, 1000, 2000, etc

**Sheet2**
Has Rows named Vancouver, Surrey, Burnaby, etc
Has Columns named 500, 1000, 2000
The cross reference cells between the rows and columns names have numerical values

**On Sheet1**
I'd like to create a cell (`B6`) that shows the value of the selection from `B4` and `B5`.
*(Ex.  `B4` you select Surrey and `B5` you select 1000.  `B6` inputs the value from Sheet2 that is from Row Surrey and Column 1000)*

**FINAL EDIT**
Here's my working code.  Special thanks to @marikamitsos

Code: `=INDEX('Value Reference'!B2:AJ6,MATCH(B4,'Value Reference'!A2:A15,0),MATCH(B5,'Value Reference'!B1:BR1,0))`

I did remove the data validation "list of item" and changed it to "List from a range" (which works much better)
Code: `'Value Reference'!A2:A15` and `'Value Reference'!B1:BR1`

Here is the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ca-buLW7i7lt8Lxw3AshDumm3g_HUPmMD2L2ZWeBj2c/edit#gid=0

Comment: Have you tried the solutions offered? Did any work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Comment: @marikamitsos while we have tags for some Google Sheets functions, they are about functions that are complex and the site already had several questions about how to use them. AFAIK the site hasn't many questions specifically about `TRANSPOSE`. Why do you think that we need this tag? Actually the current revision of this question doesn't mention TRANSPOSE so the title should be updated.

Comment: @Rubén _"AFAIK the site hasn't many questions specifically about TRANSPOSE. Why do you think that we need this tag?"_. I don't. I didn't put it there. Found it and didn't check it. It's a good thing you did.

Comment: @marikamitsos I'm sorry. It was added by another editor. That revision shouldn't be approved.

Comment: By the other hand, question title should be a summary of the question. The current title doesn't meet that rule.

Comment: @Rubén Original title didn't make much sense. Also, there was just a _minor mistake_ on the original formula. Not worthy of a title. I think making Data validation dynamic is more important. But _"INDIRECT"_? What on earth was I thinking? Please improve it.

Comment: @marikamitsos I can't at this time b/c there is and proposed edit waiting for approval.

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes your Code worked and I made some other little tweaks.  THANKS

Comment: _"...made some other little tweaks"_. If they are worth mentioning edit and add them to your question.

Comment: @marikamitsos I edited my main post with the tweaks and final code.  Thanks again for the help and helping others!

Comment: @marikamitsos FYI I did not need to use the Transpose function.  I just set the range from B1:BR1.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Great. I will erase it from the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is correct.
**You just need to use single `'` instead of double `"` quotes**.

```
=INDEX('Value Reference'!B2:AJ6,MATCH(B4,'Value Reference'!A2:A6,0),MATCH(B5,'Value Reference'!B1:AJ1,0))
```

## EDIT

### Make Data validation dynamic

You can improve your results even further.
Instead of using `List of items` for your Data validation, you can use `List from a range`.

In order to do this, follow these steps:

1. In your `Value Reference` sheet

   - Insert a new column on the left of column `A`
   - In `A1` use the formula `=(TRANSPOSE(C1:AK1))` to get the `Input Job Value`
2. In your `Main Sheet` sheet for your Data validation use:

   - For cell `B4` use `List from a range` and `'Value Reference'!B2:B7`
   - For cell `B5` use `List from a range` and `'Value Reference'!A1:A44`

Now in cell `B6` your formula becomes:

```
=INDEX('Value Reference'!C2:AK6,MATCH(D4,'Value Reference'!B2:B6,0),MATCH(D5,'Value Reference'!C1:AK1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `'Main Sheet'!B6`:

```
=query(transpose(query('Value Reference'!A1:AJ7,"Select * where A = '"&'Main Sheet'!B4&"'",-1)),"SELECT Col2 where Col1 = '"&'Main Sheet'!B5&"'",0)
```

---

**2nd Solution** :

```
    =QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Value Reference'!B1:AJ7),
    "SELECT Col"&filter(ArrayFormula(IF('Main sheet'!B4='Value Reference'!A2:A7,ROW('Value Reference'!A2:A7),)),
ArrayFormula(IF('Main sheet'!B4='Value Reference'!A2:A7,ROW('Value Reference'!A2:A7),))<>"")
    &" WHERE Col1 = '"&'Main Sheet'!B5&"'")
```

Using a `Query` is a good idea.
First the range: we use `Transpose` so we can use `Col1` for example as reference instead of `A` type of selection.

The SQL is simple : Select the column with the corresponding city `(Vancouver)`, then look for the row with the corresponding range `(1001 - 2000)`

The difficult part is to find the corresponding row in `Value Reference` of the `B5` cell in the `Main Sheet`.

I used this ugly formula that returns 2,3,4,etc.. depending of the value in `'Main sheet'!B4`:

```
filter(
ArrayFormula(IF('Main sheet'!B4='Value Reference'!A2:A7,ROW('Value Reference'!A2:A7),)),
ArrayFormula(IF('Main sheet'!B4='Value Reference'!A2:A7,ROW('Value Reference'!A2:A7),))<>"")
```

Surely you can find another way to do this but this is the quick and dirty way.

The second part of the formula is pretty much the same, trying to select the only row where there is  `(1001 - 2000)` in `Col1`. (Remember we transposed the original range).