# Copy Multiple Cells with Data Validation from one Google Sheets to Another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

I need to copy the data validation info from a column in Google Sheet (multiple cells in that column with data validation) to another Google Sheet. When doing the regular copy/paste or copy/paste Data Validation only, nothing is being "pasted".

Any idea/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but you can also copy the sheet that includes your Data Validation fields over in a/the other Spreadsheet.

Ones it's copied over (can be found at the end of the sheets), you can go ahead and copy just the field or the row/column in another sheet within this Spreadsheet document.

Had this issue many times and found this to be the best work around.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot paste validation from one Google sheet to another.**
Google Sheets does not currently have such a built-in solution.
On the other hand, when on the same sheet you can use the `Paste special` feature.

**An alternative would be to [pull your values from the other sheet for dynamic Data validation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/134537/117311)**

---

[image: paste data validation]

*In case you **really need** such functionality, you could do that using a script as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53041478/1527780)*.