# Data Validation using Named range from Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-data-validation, google-sheets-named-ranges

In Dec22 Google changed how data validation is maintained [Release note].[1](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/12/drop-down-chips-google-sheets.html)
I have thousands of cells using different ranges for validation, and it's now impossible to maintain.  
I want to change them to use named range, eg. PickGenius is a named range pointing to C1:C5, which contains a list smart people.  If I want to expend the list, I just modify the named range and all my pick lists reflect the change.
You can create data validation through GUI to use a named range, see [Named Range in validation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133523/how-to-pull-values-from-another-sheet-for-dynamic-data-validation)
However, if I try to do this through code, the destination (C1:C5) is stored rather than the name (PickGenius).

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var myRange = sheet.getRange(1,1);  
  var myRules = myRange.getDataValidations();
  var myRule=myRules[0][0];
  if (myRule !== null){
    var myVals=myRule.getCriteriaValues();
    var myrange = myVals[0].getA1Notation();    
    Logger.log(myrange);
  }
  var newrange = ss.getRangeByName("PickGenius"); 
  var newrule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(newrange).build();
  myRange.setDataValidation(newrule);
}
```

If you create a named range, run this, then goto Data>Data Validation, click on the rule, and it lists the destination as: =Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5
Is there any way to create Data Validation with a named range through code, as I have literally thousands to replace.
Thanks wonderful people.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications.  See this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729561/how-to-set-a-named-range-for-a-data-validation-programmatically-in-google-apps) on sister site Stack Overflow and this very exhaustive [**accepted answer from Tanaike**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72737883)

Comment: Many thanks @BlindSpots, just what I needed - Amazed I didn't find it myself, I searched so much.